# Nifi: how to remove session based on atribute value in nifi

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to  remove session in case  i get  certain data  from  file i  have  code  like  this,but  i got  errors  "flowfile  has  already  marked  for  removal", what  should  i change   to get  rid   of  extra errors?

1. In case  of  session rollback flowfile  will  dissapear  in queues  also?

   2.should  i  use  rollback  instead  of   remove()?

   ```
   NodeList childNodes = nodeGettingChanged.getChildNodes();
                   for (int i = 0; i != childNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
                       Node child = childNodes.item(i);
                       if (!(child instanceof Element))
                           continue;

                       if (child.getNodeName().equals("runAs")) {
                               if(child.getFirstChild().getTextContent()=="false"){

                                   session.remove(flowFile1);
                                   File deleteExtraFile =new  File("C://Users//s.tkhilaishvili//Desktop//try2//nifi-1.3.0//1//conf.xml");
                                   boolean delete=deleteExtraFile.delete();



                               }
                               else {
                                   child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("false");
                               }

                       }

                   }
   ```

   Document finalXmlDocument = xmlDocument;
                   session.write(flowFile1, new StreamCallback() {

   ```
                   public void process(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                       TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                       Transformer transformer = null;
                       try {
                           transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                       } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(finalXmlDocument);
                       ffStream.close();
                       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);


                       try {
                           transformer.transform(source, result);
                       } catch (TransformerException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
                       outputStream.write(array);
                   }

               });

                session.remove(flowFile);
               session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS);




               }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing session.remove(flowFile1) then later trying to transfer it to REL_SUCCESS, you will get that error. It looks like you already have an if-clause checking the firstChild for "false", perhaps you could put the transfer in an else-clause, such that it will only be transferred if it wasn't removed.

Comment: in  case  of  session.remove()  it  will still  be   in parent   folder  directroy?  i  mean   file  wouldn't  be  deletedm from  here